# which version of rails3 to upgrade a rails2 app to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I want to upgrade an application from Rails 2.3.14 to Rails 3.
My question is which version of 3 should I go for?

Should I go straight to the latest 3.2.2? Or should I go to a 3.0 version first?

I have already looked at various railscasts and used the rails upgrade gem, but most of the documentation is from some time ago when rails 3.0 was latest version.

Is there any reason not to go straight to 3.2.2?

Comment: 3.2.6 is the latest version as of now. 3.2.2 has sql injection vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you, I would just update incrementally, fixing problems as you go. This will make bugs easier to find, and it will keep you from going completely insane from frustration at everything that breaks. Fixing the broken stuff is easier to do in (somewhat more) bite size pieces.

More than likely, a whole bunch of crap is going to break each step of the way. (Rails 3 is basically a hybrid between Merb and Rails 2 - [a TON of stuff changed](http://www.railsdispatch.com/posts/upgrading-a-rails-2-app-to-rails-3).) Fix all that newly broken stuff. Peepcode did a [nice screencast](http://peepcode.com/blog/2010/live-coding-rails-3-upgrade) as well as the Railscasts you mentioned.

Then, once you are satisfied with your app again, upgrade to 3.1. Get the Asset Pipeline up and running and perhaps convert your app from Prototype over to jQuery because it is the new default. Fix any new bugs that got created.

Once your app is functional, upgrade to 3.2 and then try to keep it updated to the latest version as new updates come out. (Easier said than done in the Rails world.) I recommend the latest stable version because sometimes, even when they push out a major update, they'll realize they did something dumb and quickly update it again. The Rails core team doesn't get it right every single time, but they are quick to recognize their mistakes and fix them up nicely.

Good luck. :-)

Comment: I dont have any issues with prototype as I already use jQuery in the Rails 2 app. My understanding with the asset pipeline was that you dont HAVE to use it as there is a configuration option. I've already implemented most of the stuff that the rails upgrade plugin highlighted but not all as some of the changes would break the rails 2 app. Should I upgrade my Ruby from 1.8.7 at the same time (is this a requirement for 3.2?)

Comment: Okay, that's good you're already using jQuery. Yes, the asset pipeline is optional, and you will save yourself a bit of work in the update if you disable it to begin with. Rails 3.2 only requires Ruby 1.8.7, but some people prefer to update to Ruby 1.9.3 before they even update to Rails 3.0, because of the performance improvements. Note: Ruby 1.8.7 p248 and p249 have marshaling bugs that crash Rails 3. Ruby Enterprise Edition fixed them in 1.8.7-2010.02. As for 1.9, Ruby 1.9.1 is not usable because it outright segfaults, so if you want to use 1.9.x, go with 1.9.2 or newer.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely go to the latest stable version if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, no reason to hold back. Most of my applications are running 3.2.1 which isn't the latest, but is very stable.